# How to remove blank space of button inside Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

When i put button inside linearlayout, there is blank space around button. I cant remove it, How to remove it? There is a picture. as you see on left of button there is big blank space. i dont want use relative layout, because i need my webview showing half of screen size

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJIJ0.jpg

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayoutweblist"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gettitle"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".53"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="#a2aed3"
            android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="5dp"
            android:minWidth="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_highlight_off_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_gravity="right|end"
            android:gravity="right|end" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_above="@+id/webviewlay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webviewlay"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".47"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/topline"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/gettitle">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/arabicfont"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show how you want your layout to look like?

Comment: Blank space is about your progressbar.

Comment: i want that blank space in picture removed and listview cover that place. Its not progreessbar's space

Comment: what's the point in using layout_alignParentRight, layout_alignParentEnd, layout_above etc in LinearLayout. Don't those attributes just work for RelativeLayout?

Comment: My layout was relative layout before

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in linear layout so I've flatten this to a relative layout check this out:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutweblist"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#a2aed3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="5dp"
        android:minWidth="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_highlight_off_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/closebtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/progressBar"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/webviewlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        />

       <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webviewlay"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also instead of giving weight I've assigned fixed height to your webview. And by doing this you can also remove `android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"` from listview to give webview like over-lapping effect but its up to your requirement.

Comment: i dont want use android:layout_height="400dp", but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by wrapping the `ListView` and `Button` with a `FramLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutweblist"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gettitle"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".53">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="#a2aed3"
            android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="5dp"
            android:minWidth="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_highlight_off_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_gravity="right|end|bottom"
            android:gravity="right|end" />
    </FrameLayout>



    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/webviewlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webviewlay"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:layout_weight=".47"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/topline"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gettitle">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/arabicfont"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

You will need to move `android:layout_weight=".53"` from `ListView` to `FrameLayout` and add `bottom` to the `Button's` `android:layout_gravity`

Comment: Sorry still same - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCBbt.jpg
But i found soultion already, thanks.